# How to use sigsuspend with virtual timer

Tags: c, timer, signals

I want to use a virtual timer to pause a while loop till the timer expires. The goal is to have a function run periodically given a time interval.
I read on the gnu.org site that using pause() can be troublesome and they suggest using sigsuspend instead. I am using the code given in the example. My program  looks as follows.

```
void handler_SIGALRM(int signo)
{
signo = 0; /* Get rid of warning "unused parameter ‘signo’" (in a portable way). */
puts("        ***********Cleared Alarm");
return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

struct sigaction sa;
memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
sa.sa_handler = handler_SIGALRM;
if (-1 == sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, NULL ))
{
    perror("sigaction() failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

struct itimerval it_val;    /* for setting itimer */

it_val.it_value.tv_sec = 3;   // INTERVAL/1000;
it_val.it_value.tv_usec = 0;//simData.misc
it_val.it_interval = it_val.it_value;

if (setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &it_val, NULL) == -1) {
    perror("error calling setitimer()");
    exit(1);
}

sigset_t mask, oldmask;
sigemptyset(&mask);
sigaddset(&mask,SIGALRM);

/* Wait for a signal to arrive. */
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &oldmask);
sigsuspend(&oldmask);
sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, NULL);
puts("unblocked");

sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &oldmask);
while(1)
{
    //...
    sigsuspend(&oldmask);
    //...

}
sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, NULL);
return 0;
```

}

The code above accomplishes the "pause" that I need. However, when I run it embedded in another program (threaded). It just hangs, and just keeps calling _handler_SIGALRM_. 
Am I doing something wrong? Why could my program be hanging?